# Gem File won't update or install with bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, nokogiri

I'm working on Michael Hartl's RoR tutorials. I'm on chapter 3. Unfortunately, copy and pasting the gem files won't work for me, but I figured out which gem is the problem. It's the capybara gem. I've commented it out and continued the tutorial, but I'm at the point where I need to use the gem.

Here is an example $bundle update giving me an error:

```
$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........

(Removed a bunch of text)

Building nokogiri using system libraries.

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/dbz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

(Removed a bunch of text)


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/dbz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/dbz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.3.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried going to the nokogiri website and fixing the problem, but when I try to update the missing libraries (an earlier part of the error), my machine says I already have them.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  #gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'   # This line breaks everything
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

EDIT: From the http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html install page

I followed all of the steps and at the final step where I need to run the command

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2 
                    --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib 
                    --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26 
                    --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include 
                    --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
```

The output from my console is:

```
Daniels-MacBook-Air:libiconv-1.13.1 dbz$ pwd
/Users/dbz/libiconv-1.13.1
Daniels-MacBook-Air:libiconv-1.13.1 dbz$ gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-    include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2 
                    --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib 
                    --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26 
                    --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include 
                    --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
Building native extensions with: '--with-xml2-    include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2'
This could take a while...
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/dbz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-xml2-    include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit     http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/dbz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/dbz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/dbz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
Daniels-MacBook-Air:libiconv-1.13.1 dbz$                         --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib 
-bash: --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib: No such file or directory
Daniels-MacBook-Air:libiconv-1.13.1 dbz$                         --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26 
-bash: --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26: No such file or directory
Daniels-MacBook-Air:libiconv-1.13.1 dbz$                         --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include 
-bash: --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include: No such file or directory
Daniels-MacBook-Air:libiconv-1.13.1 dbz$                         --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
-bash: --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I am running OSX 10.9.3 -I'll google that

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I did. I posted an answer with the magical line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that worked:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
```

From: [Nokogiri 'Failed to build gem native extension' when I run bundle install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668684/issue-installing-nokogiri-in-bundle-install)

Source's source: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1099#issuecomment-43023208

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing some packages. Try installing them manually

For Mac OSX:

`$ sudo port install libxml2 libxslt`

With `homebrew`

`$ brew install libxml2`

Checkout this [LINK](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) here for more information. Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

Just type this in console: `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1'` then hit enter... After that finishes... run `bundle`

If you're using homebrew.. type: `brew update` then type `brew doctor`

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. I'm not sure what the brew commands do, but I tried them and then retried installing the gem and it still failed.

Comment: Does `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1'` do anything for you?

Comment: I added an edit to the question showing the first error that pops up. The gem tries to install but fails. `gem install capybara` also shoots me the error.

Comment: try `sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1'`

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved the same issue after I saw your post. It's a problem with Homebrew not including libicov with versions 9.0 and up. You'll need to manually install the library then install with the lib paths defined. See http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Comment: I'm at the `Then (finally) install nokogiri:` part and it doesn't seem to find the directories: `-bash: --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib: No such file or directory`