# An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, nokogiri

I am trying to run `bundle install` on a Mac but get an error:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I try to install nokogiri it tell me to use

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install
```

Running that doesn't seem to fix the problem.  Does anyone have  ideas  how to fix this?

Comment: have you see this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528839/why-does-installing-nokogiri-on-mac-os-fail-with-libiconv-is-missing?rq=1)

Comment: Can you post your ruby version and OS? Also what happens when you try `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8'`

Comment: Also check out one of [SO posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336035/gem-file-wont-update-or-install-with-bundler/25343391#25343391)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Failed to build gem native extension' when I run bundle install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668684/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-when-i-run-bundle-install)

Comment: Hey Aaron, can you post what happens when you `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8'`? This will let us know the root of the problem