# Failing to install Nokogiri gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, paperclip, nokogiri

I'm working on a rails app that allows for image attachments to each use account. I'm using paperclip and amazon web services:

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

When I run bundle install, I get this message:

extconf failed, exit code 1

```
Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.5/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I try running 'gem install nokogiri', I get this message:

extconf failed, exit code 1

```
Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.5/gem_make.out
```

My OS is Mac OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks. **What's going on here? How can I get nokogiri to install and behave properly?**

**Full stack trace**:

```
Building native extensions with: '--use-system-libraries'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... yes
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-exslt-dir
    --without-exslt-dir
    --with-exslt-include
    --without-exslt-include=${exslt-dir}/include
    --with-exslt-lib
    --without-exslt-lib=${exslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libexslt-config
    --without-libexslt-config

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.5/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This works like a charm!

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24511149

Comment: It worked, but only after I updated the path to libxml2 (for future users)

Answer (score 11):

On Ubuntu, try installing the following dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc ruby-dev libxslt-dev libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried `gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.5 -- --use-system-libraries`?Most nokogiri errors are to do with libxml2, libxslt or libiconv config.

Nokogiri [docs](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) should give you more instructions. If the solution doesn't work, you may want to post full stack trace so others can help more.

Comment: right, you need to install libxml2 :), run `brew install libxml2` first then try again. If you get error with libxslt and libiconv then do the same

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but didnt work, it keeps telling me the libxml2 is already installed, see my answer

Comment: I really appreciate you looking into this!! :))

Comment: See my answer below—I haven't found it documented anywhere, but this is **the simplest** way to get nokogiri to install on Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks . That worked for me. I am using ubuntu on WSL

Answer (score 7):

after upgrading to Rails 4.2.4 (which inculdes Nokogiri `1.6.6.2`) on Ubuntu 14.04 (I'm using RVM) I needed to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

Comment: I was trying so hard and installed almost all the libraries 10 times. FINALLY "libgmp3-dev" worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As per the nokogiri installation instruction installing,

`sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

solved the issue for me.

Comment: `zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.`

Comment: Worked for me as well on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP was referencing `bundle install` which I happened to use as well I think it is worth pointing out the [Installing Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) page which eventually revealed the most elegant solution (which worked for me also on Mac OS X 10.8.5):

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

This instructs bundler to install nokogiri as in the answers of @kasperite

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by installing the xcode dependencies that Nokogiri needs to be installed:

```
xcode-select --install
```

After that run bundle install again and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Package that did it:

```
apt-get install libghc-zlib-dev
```

Other possible candidate:

`zlib1g-dev` on 12.04

found it [here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1188)

Answer (score 1):

To take from [dylanjhunt's awesome answer on Github](https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan/issues/876#issuecomment-170403692), just in case anyone hasn't tried it,

> Just to add to this, I was having a very similar issue that was
>   resolved by updating dev tools.
>
> `xcode-select --install`
>
> Hoping someone sees this that had not tried doing this yet and it
>   helps.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the same error message as you, but I wanted to note what I finally found as the **extraordinarily simple solution** for installing nokogiri on Ubuntu:

**Turns out the nokogiri build process depends on `patch`.**

**Run: `sudo apt-get install patch`**

I was working on a VM (a vagrant box, actually), which is why I didn't already have `patch` installed.

The error I got (after a lot of other stuff that looked like an error but was actually just a warning) was:

```
Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... ERROR, review '/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/patch.log' to see what happened.
```

I've deleted the log by now (the above was in my terminal session), but the `patch.log` file referenced above was absurdly simple; it just said something like `patch not found`.

Boy did I feel silly for all the digging around I did installing libraries trying to fix it!  :)

Answer (score 0):

install gcc first

in *buntu :
    apt-get install gcc

after that U may requer most dev libs, such as
libxml2 / zlib / etc.
see build log(path in my case) :
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/mkmf.log
for string like - fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

> I had the same issue earlier today. I had updated my xcode and had not
>   agreed to the terms yet. Running sudo `xcodebuild -license` and agreeing
>   got my bundle working again.

- https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1727#issuecomment-194568428