# Error while installing Nokogiri (1.6.7) on El Capitan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, nokogiri

One of my developers have updated Nokogiri, and when pulling the updated Gemfile my `bundle install` fails.

```
➜  my-project git:(master) bundle install
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.3
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.0.0

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
  --help
  --clean
  --use-system-libraries
  --with-zlib-dir
  --without-zlib-dir
  --with-zlib-include
  --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
  --with-zlib-lib
  --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
  --with-xml2-dir
  --without-xml2-dir
  --with-xml2-include
  --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
  --with-xml2-lib
  --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
  --with-libxml-2.0-config
  --without-libxml-2.0-config
  --with-pkg-config
  --without-pkg-config
  --with-xslt-dir
  --without-xslt-dir
  --with-xslt-include
  --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
  --with-xslt-lib
  --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
  --with-libxslt-config
  --without-libxslt-config
  --with-exslt-dir
  --without-exslt-dir
  --with-exslt-include
  --without-exslt-include=${exslt-dir}/include
  --with-exslt-lib
  --without-exslt-lib=${exslt-dir}/lib
  --with-libexslt-config
  --without-libexslt-config

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-project/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@my-project/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.7/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

As suggested in "[Failing to install Nokogiri gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496498/failing-to-install-nokogiri-gem/27696382#27696382)" I have unsuccessfully tried to run:

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

As suggested in "[Failing to install Nokogiri gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496498/failing-to-install-nokogiri-gem/27496640#27496640)" I also tried:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

and:

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.5 -- --use-system-libraries
```

My OS version is El Capitan 10.11.2, and I have checked that the Xcode licence agreement has been accepted.

Any ideas how to get the Nokogiri installation to succeed?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You should install `xcode-select` packages first, then try installing nokogiri again. Try these commands,

```
xcode-select --install
```

then try

```
gem install nokogiri
```

with whatever Nokogiri version you want.

Nokogiri depends on multiple libraries like libxslt, libxml and zlib. Dev versions (including source) of these should be installed before installing Nokogiri in any Linux distribution. For OS X, the above command should work I guess.

The actual solution is in the comments below.

Answer (score 33):

Try this :

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/lib/
```

And then run

```
bundle update
```

I hope this could help you :)

Answer (score 8):

I you're using homebrew to maintain libraries like libml on your mac, the following command on your mac might help:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8' -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/include/libxml2  --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/lib/
```

just ensure that the path for libxml is same as mine unless brew changes with the next version. You can check this by running the below command:

```
brew info libxml2
```

Answer (score 3):

*Edit Updated work good with MacOS Sierra :*

```
xcode-select --install
```

---

Add `gem "nokogiri", ">= 1.6.7.rc3"` in your Gemfile

and then run

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

try to:

```
apt-get install ruby-nokogiri
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting this! I finally got nokogirl to run with `bundle install` correctly for my app after running the following:

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating Xcode and Command Line Tools fixed all the errors for me. After that I could install Nokogiri with gem install nokogiri and after that gem install rails worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

Run the following to install RVM and the latest stable version of Ruby:
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

Install the Ruby interpreter:

rvm install 2.1.0 --autolibs=enable

After that's finished installing, run:

source /Users/{your_user_name}/.rvm/scripts/rvm
Run:

ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]


==> sudo gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.14.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.14.6
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.14.6
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.14.6
Done installing documentation for bundler after 4 seconds
1 gem installed
```