# El Capitan Mac OSX doesn't bundle nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xcode, nokogiri

I'm trying to run `gem install nokogiri` on 10.11 OSX and getting the following error. Note I just updated to the newest XCode version 8.0:

```
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
```

I've tried everything that was listed here but wasn't able to figure it out: [Error while installing Nokogiri (1.6.7) on El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651519/error-while-installing-nokogiri-1-6-7-on-el-capitan)

Comment: just tried `brew uninstall xz` and it worked. Not sure why this was the case though.

Comment: Did you accept the user TOS for Xcode? http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/175069/1153