# Can't run rails new <project> successfully due to failure of installing Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

My OS is OS X Sierra, and my **ruby** and **rails** versions are as following:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]
$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.2
```

I encountered the following error when I was trying to create a new rails project.

```
$ rails new hellorails
      create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/assets/javascripts/channels
      create  app/assets/javascripts/channels/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/update
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/spring.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 12.0.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.8.1
Using minitest 5.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using rack 2.0.1
Using nio4r 2.0.0
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 7.1.4
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using bundler 1.12.4
Using byebug 9.0.6
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using thor 0.19.4
Using ffi 1.9.18
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.8
Using puma 3.8.2
Using sass 3.4.23
Using tilt 2.0.7
Using sqlite3 1.3.13
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.3
Installing nokogiri 1.7.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/kenshinji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170409-1441-uzertk.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/kenshinji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
/Users/kenshinji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/kenshinji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
    from /Users/kenshinji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
    from /Users/kenshinji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:138:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:162:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /Users/kenshinji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:619:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:161:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:406:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/kenshinji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/kenshinji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.7.1/gem_make.out
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using mime-types 3.1
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.1.13
Using rb-inotify 0.9.8
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using activesupport 5.0.2
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.7.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.1'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
Could not find gem 'coffee-rails (~> 4.2)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

It seems the error is due to failure of installing **Nokogiri**, I've tried the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651519/error-while-installing-nokogiri-1-6-7-on-el-capitan). None of them works.

Comment: try this  : gem install bundler && rbenv rehash

Comment: it might be version issue, did you run this bundle exec spring binstub --all,  gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.1 ,  bundle install

Comment: It is complaining about development tools. You should have Xcode installed on your mac. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651519/error-while-installing-nokogiri-1-6-7-on-el-capitan

Comment: also, check, nokogiri installtion webpage http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#mac_os_x

Answer (score 0):

After checking the [official website about installing Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#mac_os_x), and I ran the following command , my problem was solved magically.

```
brew reinstall xz --universal
```

I think the Nokogiri document explains pretty well as below.

> When using Homebrew, there are several libraries that use a formula called xz (including the_silver_searcher and imagemagick), which by default installs a version of liblzma that is incompatible with most Ruby builds. (Homebrew installs only the 64-bit version of the library, but most Ruby builds are universal.) This can be fixed in a couple of ways: