# Metasploit Update: Error In Bundle Install ( nokogiri 1.6.8 )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, bundle, metasploit

Metasploit was working fine until this morning when I updated it with `msfupdate`, then all went to heck.

Typing `msfconsole` Now gives me this error:

```
Could not find nokogiri-1.6.8 in any of the sources
Run bundle install to install missing gems.
```

I went and typed `bundle install`.  It was going fine until this happened:

```
Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/usr/bin/ruby2.2 -r ./siteconf20160831-24032-1wim46x.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
Using pkg-config version 1.1.7
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
checking for libxml-2.0... no
checking for libxslt... no
checking for libexslt... no
ERROR: cannot discover where libxml2 is located on your system. please make sure pkg-config is installed.
* extconf.rb failed *
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.2
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-override-variables
    --without-override-variables
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-exslt-dir
    --without-exslt-dir
    --with-exslt-include
    --without-exslt-include=${exslt-dir}/include
    --with-exslt-lib
    --without-exslt-lib=${exslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libexslt-config
    --without-libexslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using faraday 0.9.2
Using jsobfu 0.4.1
Using packetfu 1.1.11
Using rex-arch 0.1.1
Using rex-ole 0.1.2
Using rex-random_identifier 0.1.0
Using rex-zip 0.1.0
Using simplecov 0.12.0
Using activesupport 4.2.7.1
Using tzinfo-data 1.2016.6
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8' succeeds before bundling.
```

I started searching and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020478/error-installing-nokogiri-on-bundle-install-but-already-installed), which suggested that I should run `bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries`

But again, nothing.  I also tried `gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.8`.  I also tried even older versions: `gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.0`.

I'm using Kali.

---

**EDIT:** I think the solution is that I should reinstall Kali; One thing i learned from all this is to **NEVER** update MSF :D

Comment: can you please give your gemfile and ruby version here?

Comment: @SantoshSharma Dont know how to do that(Im a newbie), can you tell me how to do so?

Comment: please see link that u r given here. in that question gemfile available

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a non-programming tool, and SO is for programming questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@RUser98 --

I found this answer on the Unix Stack Exchange site maybe it will help you?

> If you get a error installing `nokogiri-1.6.8` try to:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev --yes
> ```

Source: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/298159

I've also had numerous issues with installing/updating Metasploit on Kali each time something new so I feel your pain

Comment: Up voted because this caused `bundle install` to work just fine, But I'm still getting errors on running `msfconsole`

Comment: It might still be helpful to others if you posted the error and solution ;)
Either way nice work on fixing it!

Answer (score 6):

If you're having this problem On MacOS when trying to install Nokogiri, you can run `xcode-select --install` and try again :)

Answer (score 0):

First i tried these:-

```
sudo apt-get install make
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

Once the nogogiri gem was installed, I went into the metasploit-framework directory in my case was:-

`cd /usr/share/metasploit-framework` and typed:-

```
sudo bundle install
```

Everything went on nicely till i encountered a 'pg' gem installation error.
This solves the error:-

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
sudo gem install pg -v '0.21.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
sudo bundle install
```

And yet again I encountered another gem installation error named 'pcaprub'

This Solves it:-

```
sudo apt install libpcap-dev
sudo gem install pcaprub -v '0.13.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
sudo bundle install
```

Okay it's getting really frustrating now as yet again another error has occurred this time it was the 'sqlite3' gem which can be fixed by:-

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
sudo gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
sudo bundle install
```

Ah! finally Metasploit is Up and Running.

```
Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 144 gems now installed.
```