# How to install Nokogiri on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: xcode, macos, rubygems, jekyll

I've been trying to install Nokogiri but I end up with errors.
I got a Jekyll site, hosted on Github, and when I try `bundle install` once the site is cloned, I end up with an error when Nokogiri is being installed.

1. First I tried these two:

   ```
   bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
   bundle install.
   ```

   which gave me the following error:

   ```
   Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
   An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
   ```
2. On my second install try I used:

   ```
   gem install nokogiri
   ```

   which lead me to the following error message:

   ```
   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
       ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

           current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri
       /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160916-79204-14q5l5.rb extconf.rb
       Using pkg-config version 1.1.7
       checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
       checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
       Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
       Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
       checking for iconv.h... yes
       checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
       checking for iconv... yes
       ************************************************************************
       IMPORTANT NOTICE:

       Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4.

       Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
       updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
       to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
       reinstall nokogiri as follows:

           gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
               [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
               [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

       If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

           bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
           bundle install

       Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
       versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
       ************************************************************************
       Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
       Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
       Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
       ========================================================================
         CCLD     libxml2.la
         CC       testdso.lo
         CCLD     testdso.la
         CC       xmllint.o
         CCLD     xmllint
       ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.2/lib/liblzma.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.2/lib/liblzma.dylib
       Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
         "_lzma_auto_decoder", referenced from:
             _xz_head in libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
         "_lzma_code", referenced from:
             _xz_decomp in libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
         "_lzma_end", referenced from:
             ___libxml2_xzclose in libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
         "_lzma_properties_decode", referenced from:
             _is_format_lzma in libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
       make[2]: *** [xmllint] Error 1
       make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
       make: *** [all] Error 2
       ========================================================================
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.

       Provided configuration options:
           --with-opt-dir
           --without-opt-dir
           --with-opt-include
           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
           --with-opt-lib
           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
           --with-make-prog
           --without-make-prog
           --srcdir=.
           --curdir
           --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
           --help
           --clean
           --use-system-libraries
           --enable-static
           --disable-static
           --with-zlib-dir
           --without-zlib-dir
           --with-zlib-include
           --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
           --with-zlib-lib
           --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
           --enable-cross-build
           --disable-cross-build
       /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'
           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'
           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'
           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'
           from extconf.rb:364:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
           from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
           from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
           from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
           from extconf.rb:363:in `block in process_recipe'
           from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
           from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
           from extconf.rb:555:in `<main>'

       To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

         /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/mkmf.log

       extconf failed, exit code 1

       Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8 for inspection.
       Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
   ```

Comment: This solved it on my installation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29021223

Comment: @lem0nlite didn't work I'm afraid, thanks though! I updated at the top with a new error message I received.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after using rbenv and RVM to upgrade Ruby and use the command:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Comment: Since RVM and rbenv aim to solve the same problem and could conflict, I'd suggest using one rather than both at the same time.

Comment: rbenv and RVM will fight for control. Pick one and use it. From [the rbenv installation notes](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation): `"rbenv is incompatible with RVM. Please make sure to fully uninstall RVM and remove any references to it from your shell initialization files before installing rbenv."`